# Define class as global variable in Typescript to use without import it in js later

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im sure there is already a answer out there, but i searched for an hour straight and cannot get it to work.

I'm trying to refactor some old code, where only vars and global vars were used. I thought i start implementing the two constructors (if you can call them so) as new classes, but still use them in js as global vars (without any import statements). For the first example that went well, i didn't even had to export the class but just included it via the index.html file and used it in js code like before. On the second class however i encountered some Problems, i had to import code from another js file, so i included requireJs in the Project and imported it by `import qSVG = require('../js/qSVG.js');`. Through using requireJs and switching to `"module": "AMD"` in my tsconfig i made a module out of it, thus not being able to use it anywhere else.
I can't rewrite the whole Project at once, so i need to call it in the same way as before.

How can i accomplish that?

How can I export this to the global namespace so every file knows about it without any imports?

*tsconfig.json (just extended default generated by webstorm)*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "AMD",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017"],
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

*two-dimensional-object.ts*

```
import $ = require('../../libraries/jquery.min.js');
import qSVG = require('../js/qSVG.js');

export class TwoDimensionalObject {
    /* some properties */

    constructor(/*params*/) {
        // initialisation code
    }

    public update(): boolean {
       // some code
    }
}
```

*editor.js*

```
function _MOUSEMOVE(event) {
    /* some code */
    binder = new TwoDimensionalObject(/*params*/)
    /* some code */
}
```

**I tried a few things already**

- just add to window object like: 
  `(window as any).TwoDimensionalObject = TwoDimensionalObject`
- extend window object like:

```
declare global {
    interface Window { TwoDimensionalObject: any; }
}

window.TwoDimensionalObject = window.TwoDimensionalObject;
```

- declare as const like:

`declare const TwoDimensionalObject = TwoDimensionalObject;`

Comment: If you only care about the shape of the data at this point, interfaces instead of classes might be a good bet - they require being imported into the .ts file, but don't show up in the transpiled .js.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the window object:

*two-dimensional-object.ts*

```
...
export class TwoDimensionalObject {
   ...
}
...

window['TwoDimensionalObject'] = TwoDimensionalObject;
alert('TwoDimensionalObject class is now global!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
```

Make sure it will be executed in some way, like in some entry file:

*main.ts* (entry code)

```
import './two-dimensional-object';
```

Comment: i tried this already (sorry should have wrote this in the question), but either it throughs *window.TwoDimensionalObject is not a constructor*  or *TwoDimensionalObject is not defined* (i think the second way is the coreect way to call it isn't it?)

Comment: I think this is because the code in file 'two-dimensional-object.ts' is never being executed. You should import it in some entry file, so your class can be defined and set in the window object

Comment: You only need to extend the window object typing if you need to access it from another "ts" files with type check. In .js files it would be indifferent.

Comment: Is this question so bad written or does nobody has an answer for this???

Comment: Did you really try my suggestion? (1) Declare the class and window var attribuition in the same file. (2) Make sure it is being executed (put an alert at the bottom of the file).

Comment: yeah i'm sure it is being executed, but it just won't work